# Microsoft Graph returning Resource Not Found

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I've registered an app in Azure AD and given it API permissions(both Application and delegated) to read all AD groups (`Group.Read.All`, also `Directory.Read.All` etc). Using this app I am using Graph Service Client to make a call to get user's AD groups.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<GroupInfo>> GetAllGroupsOfUser(string mail)
    {
        IList<GroupInfo> result = new List<GroupInfo>();

        IUserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage memberOfGroups = await _graphServiceClient.Users[mail].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();

       .......... More code ........
     }
```

It works fine for most of the users email but for few emails, which are present in the active directory, I'm getting the following exception

`Code: Request_ResourceNotFound Message: Resource 'someuser@somedomain.co' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.`

Comment: The error states that the user is not present in AAD.The users may not have synced to the AzureAD from AD. Check if that user is present in Azure AD or not and then give a try with the same user.

Comment: That was the 1st thing I checked these users are present in AD

Comment: Were they present in Azure Active Directory? Because Microsoft Graph API checks the users in Azure Active Directory but not on-premise AD.

Comment: I have checked again, in the AAD on azure portal, and the user is showing directory synched.

Comment: Are the users Guests?

Comment: No, they are organization users, one of the user I m testing is present since 2016 and member of around seventy AD groups

Comment: The last thing we can do is debug the mail that you are passing and compare it with the Azure AD user's UPN(UserPrincipalName) and Also try it in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN`

Comment: I've used Graph Explorer, and its great, but It won't let me test users other than myself. e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users/myname@mydomain/memberOf` works fine but If I use another email I get access error, even when I try the app access token, Are you sure we can user graph explorer to test other users?

Comment: Yes, we can. You just need to have Directory.Read.All permission.

Comment: I do have the `Directory.Read.All` permission set for the App that calls the MS graph api. How can I pass/set the app permissions in the Graph Explorer?

Comment: You can see modify permissions option just below HTTP request textbox.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I have clientId and client secret that I can to use to make calls via graph explorer. Any idea how can I use them in graph explorer? can you point me any example, thanks

Comment: Graph Explorer is also an app in your tenant which uses a user context flow and get the user token and it also needs permissions separately. So, as you already have a token for your own app you can use it in POSTMAN and make the call.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma I have the same issue. I m able to generate app access token and when I try via graph explorer I m getting the same error `Resource 'usersemail@test.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.` This is an active synced user in Azure AD

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not that you lack certain permissions, and it has nothing to do with which api testing tool you are using. Your error is very simple. As your error message says, it is that you entered the wrong user email.

Your error message has clearly stated that there is no'`someuser@somedomain.co`' email, because this is not a correct email, it should be `.com` instead of `.co`.

So you must make sure that you enter the correct email without **special characters** or **spaces**.

This is my test result:

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, the email I m trying is correct. I have just put a demo email in the question to hide the actual email.

Comment: @rumi   Are all users in one tenant? How about if you use postman to test?